# MapServer | Cant Get WMS GetFeatureInfo To Return GeoJSON

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I have MapServer serving up a whole bunch of data, and everything is working good.  One area I am stuck is getting the WMS GetFeatureInfo request to return GeoJSON.  Regardless of what I try, I just get plain text back.

The applicable pieces of my mapfile are below.  My understanding is that the OGR/GEOJSON driver (in OUTPUTFORMAT) makes it so that I dont need to use a template.  Is that correct?  I've found that if I dont include some dummy TEMPLATE in the LAYER - the layer is not queryable.  With the below configuration - regardless of what I set info_format (or outputformat) to - I just get plain text response back.

**Example response:**

> GetFeatureInfo results:
>
> Layer 'treecrowns'   Feature 42342:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "geojson"
        DRIVER "OGR/GEOJSON"
        MIMETYPE "application/json; subtype=geojson"
        FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=stream"
        FORMATOPTION "FORM=SIMPLE"
END

 WEB
        QUERYFORMAT "geojson"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "DAM WMS"
            "wms_abstract" "DAM WMS"
            #"wms_onlineresource" "http://mapserver//mapserv"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
            "wms_encoding" "UTF-8"
            "wms_enable_request" "*"
            "wfs_enable_request" "!*"
            "wfs_encoding" "UTF-8"
            "wfs_getfeature_formatlist" "gml,geojson"
        END
END

LAYER
    NAME "treecrowns"
    TYPE POLYGON
    TEMPLATE fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo # For GetFeatureInfo
    EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER" # For performance
    CONNECTION "host=x.x.x.x port=5432 dbname=x user=x password=x"
    DATA "geom from treecrowns"
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "treecrowns" # For WMS
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:4978" # For WMS

        "wfs_enable_request" "*" # Enable WFS for this layer
        "gml_include_items" "all" # For GetFeatureInfo and WFS GetFeature (QueryBuilder)
        "ows_geom_type" "Polygon" # For returning geometries in GetFeatureInfo
        "ows_geometries" "geom" # For returning geometries in GetFeatureInfo
        "wfs_featureid" "name"

        "wms_metadataurl_href" "http://www.example.com/bar" # For metadata URL
        "wms_metadataurl_format" "text/html" # For metadata URL
        "wms_metadataurl_type" "TC211" # For metadata URL
        "wfs_getfeature_formatlist" "gml,geojson"
    END
    STATUS ON
    PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
    END
    CLASS
        NAME "treecrowns"
        STYLE
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 255
            WIDTH 2
        END
        STYLE
            COLOR 0 0 255
            OPACITY 40
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: @nmtoken.  that did the trick!  if you post as an answer - i will give you credit

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify wanted formats in the "WMS_FEATURE_INFO_MIME_TYPE"